# Outlook GetFreeBusy method returns error message

Tags: vb.net, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I programmed a VSTO add-in for outlook. Outlook runs in a Microsoft Exchange environment. We use Office 365.
I would like to determine the availability of the ExchangeUser in the next few days. The GetFreeBusy function would actually be ideal for this.
Unfortunately, I get an error message when I call it.

**Error code -2147352567 (0x80020009)**
**Frei/Gebucht-Informationen können nicht geladen werden.**
(Unable to load free/busy information.)

Here is the relevant VB.NET code:

```
    Dim strFreeBusy As String
    Dim CurrentExchangeUser As ExchangeUser = CurrentNamespace.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
    strFreeBusy = CurrentExchangeUser.GetFreeBusy(Now, 60)
```

I also tested the whole thing in an Outlook VBA macro.
Using "Microsoft Outlook 16.0 Object Library".

```
    Sub Test_1()
        Dim oManager As ExchangeUser
        Dim oCurrentUser As ExchangeUser
        Dim FreeBusy As String
        Dim BusySlot As Long
        Dim DateBusySlot As Date
        Dim i As Long
        Const SlotLength = 60
        'Get ExchangeUser for CurrentUser
        If Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.Type = "EX" Then
            Set oCurrentUser = Application.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser
        End If

        FreeBusy = oCurrentUser.GetFreeBusy(Now, SlotLength)

    End Sub
```

The GetFreeBusy function call aborts with the same error message as in .NET.

Any idea how to get the function GetFreeBusy working?

Comment: Can Outlook itself show F/B OK?

Comment: Does it work in Outlook VBA? If not, have you tried to check that manually?

Comment: @Dmitry: In Outlook Planning View I can see the Free/Busy status.@

Comment: @Eugene: In Outlook VBA the GetFreeBusy method returns the same error message. "... check manually" -> I may not understand correctly. But in the planning view I see the absence status (OOF) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the online mode with Exchange instead of cached one. Sometimes it helps to retrieve the free/busy information correctly.

Comment: I switched off the Exchange-Cache-Mode as a test. Unfortunately, the GetFreeBusy function still returns errors.

Comment: Try to re-create a mail profile. Do you get the same problem there?

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but after a longer wait I tested the GetFreeBusy method again without any changes. To my surprise, it now works as expected. I can only assume that the exchange server had some problem. And what I also don't have control over is what our IT in the company is configuring on the exchange server ...